# Using play with collect in twilio autopilot

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to use play in conjunction with twilio autopilot? I tried to add `question:{play:{url:<url>, loop:1}}` but it just gave me errors. I am unable to find documentation of this feature and was hoping I just missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Play is an Autopilot action. Did you make sure you are using a current version of the Twilio Helper Libraries?

Autopilot Play Action
https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/play

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "play": {
                "loop": 2,
                "url": "https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't use a play action within a collect action.

You can use a say action for a question, in which [you can use SSML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/say#example-3-say-with-ssml) to better control the synthesized speech.